# Finding Minimum For every group in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I have a class as below.

```
public class Employee{
int EmployeeDepartmentId;
int EmplyoyeeId;
int Salary;
}
```

I an creating an ArrayList as Below.

```
ArrayList<Employee> arrEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>;
```

Now, I want to find out List of employees from every department with minimum salary.

How can this be achieved. I tried using `Collections.Min()`, but that will give me the minimum salary from whole list. I want it to be grouped by department.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a separate list for each department.

Comment: Can I get somehow a sublist with all the employees belonging to one department? I mean it should traverse through the main list, create sub list for 1st department, find min and save in another arraylist and then check for next department. Can this be done?

Comment: I don't see how without parsing the whole list.

Comment: Or At least somehow if i can get a sub list that will list all the departments distinctly?

Comment: As far as i know there is nothing like linq in c# to filter data in collections.

so you have to filter the List yourself.

Comment: See my answer for more details (based on Jim's answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do two runs. The first to group the employees by department, perhaps using a map:

```
Map<Integer,List<Employee>>
```

Then loop over this map grabbing the minimum of each list.

Comment: @Tushar Vengurlekar No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea by Jim, something like this should work:

```
Map<Integer, List<Employee>> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, List<Employee>>();
int i = 0;
int size = arrEmployee.size();
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    Employee emp = arrEmployee.get(i);
    List<Employee> list = hmap.get(emp.EmployeeDepartmentId);
    if (list == null)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<Employee>();       
    }
    list.add(emp);
    hmap.put(emp.EmployeeDepartmentId, list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make your own comparator :

```
Collections.min(list,new Comparator<Employee>() {
              public int compare(Employee  e1, Employee e2) {
                        return e2.getSalary().compareTo(e1.getSalary());
                    }
                });
```

I Hope this help.

This will only get the minimum salary.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand the problem correctly. He wants distincts minimums for each different EmployeeDepartmentId.

Answer (score 0):

every logic is in Comparator they will be grouped by department and sorted by salary:

```
public class Employee {
Integer EmployeeDepartmentId;
Integer EmplyoyeeId;
Integer Salary;

public Employee(Integer employeeDepartmentId, Integer emplyoyeeId, Integer salary)  {
    EmployeeDepartmentId = employeeDepartmentId;
    EmplyoyeeId = emplyoyeeId;
    Salary = salary;
}

public Integer getEmployeeDepartmentId() {
    return EmployeeDepartmentId;
}

public void setEmployeeDepartmentId(Integer employeeDepartmentId) {
    EmployeeDepartmentId = employeeDepartmentId;
}

public Integer getEmplyoyeeId() {
    return EmplyoyeeId;
}

public void setEmplyoyeeId(Integer emplyoyeeId) {
    EmplyoyeeId = emplyoyeeId;
}

public Integer getSalary() {
    return Salary;
}

public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
    Salary = salary;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employees=new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employees.add(new Employee(3, 3, 50));
    employees.add(new Employee(2, 4, 2500));
    employees.add(new Employee(1, 1, 100));
    employees.add(new Employee(2, 5, 1100));
    employees.add(new Employee(1, 2, 20));
    for(Employee e:employees)
        System.out.println(e.getEmployeeDepartmentId()+" "+e.getEmplyoyeeId()+" "+e.getSalary());
    Collections.sort(employees,new Comparator<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Employee e, Employee e1) {
            if(e.getEmployeeDepartmentId()==e1.getEmployeeDepartmentId()){
                return e.getSalary().compareTo(e1.getSalary());
            }else
                return e.getEmployeeDepartmentId().compareTo(e1.getEmployeeDepartmentId());
        }
    });
    for(Employee e:employees)
        System.out.println(e.getEmployeeDepartmentId()+" "+e.getEmplyoyeeId()+" "+e.getSalary());
}
```

}

Comment: This is not one pass. In addition the the pass , the sort will take `n(log n)`, making the total complexity `n + n(log n)`. Putting into a map, then iterating the map is '2n' which is guaranteed to be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it youself:

```
Map<Integer, Employee> minSalary = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
for(Employee emp : employeeList) {
    Integer depId = emp.getDepartmentId();
    if(minSalary.containsKey(depId )) {
        if(emp.getSalary() < minSalary.get(depId).getSalary()) {
            minSalary.put(depId, emp);
        }
    }
    else {
        minSalary.put(depId, emp);
    }
}
```

Note that only one `Employee` is stored with minimal salary, but it is sufficient when you only want to know the salary. If you really need all employees with the minimal salary, you need a `Map<Integer, List<Employee>>`.
In that case i'd recommend to store the `Employees` redundantly in a `List<Employee>` and a `` `Map<Integer, List<Employee>> `` (per departmentID, as suggested by other answers.